# Plan select query with data load is performing slow in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-tuning

Database - Oracle 11g

We have a table TB_ETD_NON_MKTS_TRANS_OP with 30 million records

We have indexes on REPORTING_PARTY, REPORTING_TIMESTAMP.

We are executing query as

```
SELECT *
FROM
(select 
  COUNT(*) OVER () CNT,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY REPORTING_TIMESTAMP DESC NULLS LAST) RN,
  OP.* 
from TB_ETD_NON_MKTS_TRANS_OP OP 
WHERE REPORTING_PARTY = 'SB'
AND REPORTING_TIMESTAMP >= TO_DATE('11-JAN-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')
AND REPORTING_TIMESTAMP <= TO_DATE('14-JAN-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')
)
WHERE RN >= '1'
AND RN   <= '20';
```

**Explain plan output is as below**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |                          |  1726K|   502G|       |   362K  (1)| 01:12:36 |
|*  1 |  VIEW               |                          |  1726K|   502G|       |   362K  (1)| 01:12:36 |
|   2 |   WINDOW SORT       |                          |  1726K|  1330M|  1926M|   362K  (1)| 01:12:36 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TB_ETD_NON_MKTS_TRANS_OP |  1726K|  1330M|       | 69286   (2)| 00:13:52 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("RN">=1 AND "RN"<=20)
   3 - filter("REPORTING_TIMESTAMP">=TO_DATE(' 2015-01-11 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
              AND "REPORTING_PARTY"='SOB' AND "REPORTING_TIMESTAMP"<=TO_DATE(' 2015-01-14 00:00:00', 
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

Comment: Unrelated but: don't compare apples to oranges. `rn` is a number. `'1'` is a character value, `1` is a number. Never use single quotes for numbers.

Comment: Do you have two single column indexes or is that one index on `REPORTING_PARTY, REPORTING_TIMESTAMP` ?

Comment: The estimated rows are `1726K`, how many rows are actually returned? If there is a huge difference, you need to gather statistics again.

Comment: REPORTING_PARTY, REPORTING_TIMESTAMP are 2 seperate nonunique indexes

Comment: Actual returned rows are only 20, as we have RN=1 and RN=20

Comment: Is REPORTING_TIMESTAMP of type `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`? In second case you should use `TO_TIMESTAMP()` instead of `TO_DATE()`.

Comment: This is taking more time "(ORDER BY REPORTING_TIMESTAMP DESC NULLS LAST)"